# custom WordPress tag.php page .. trying to get tag info

Tags: tags, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm creating a custom tag.php page for a WordPress theme.

I need to get the name, id and slug for the tag page that I am one (i.e. www.site.com/tag/fruit/ )... I see tons of examples online about how to list the tags for a page/post, but none that say how to easily get the name, id and slug for a specific tag page.

I tried to use the following... but the code below is for cycling through all the tags in a post. I just need the one tag for that tag page. If I try the option below, I don't get the correct tag (it picks some other tag on my site).

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
          foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                $tag_id = $tag->term_id;
                $tag_name = $tag->name;
                $tag_slug = $tag->slug;
          }
        }

        echo "<!-- tag_id: ".$tag_id." -->";
        echo "<!-- tag_name: ".$tag_name." -->";
        echo "<!-- tag_slug: ".$tag_slug." -->";
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Exactly what tag info do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your tag page, and for that matter, any taxonomy/term page, you can get the info from the current term being viewed with `get_queried_object()`. This will return the whole term object.

If you just need the ID, you can use `get_queried_object_id()`

Example:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
var_dump( $term );
```